# Delete my profile picture from Wherevent

Tags: facebook-events

There is an event promoting website named Wherevent. It aggregates, through a Facebook-linked created-apparently out-of-thin-air account, in a very similar manner to Scribd and the like, data on events you attended (or just confirmed for that matter).

A simple googling of my name brings up an old picture from my deactivated facebook account.

I've tried everything I can think of: join again and decline the event on Facebook, look up for my name on the guest list (1,000-plus, didn't find myself), change my profile name... even delete the account on Wherevent: it just doesn't work.

Any thoughts on how can I delete successfully (or otherwise erase that picture) that account on Wherevent?